# How to call "mysql" with STDIN redirection from inside Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to use redirection to load a SQL database schema using:

```
system("mysql -p -h db.server.local -u admin -D some_db < schema.sql")
```

I expect it to prompt for a password, and it works correctly when run from IRB. However, when run via Rails' runner it fails
as if I had hit the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key at the password prompt. In Rails console it looks like this:

```
pry(main)> system("mysql -p -h db.server.local -u admin -D some_db < schema.sql")
Enter password: ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'admin'@'mylocalpc' (using password: NO)
```

It did not give me a chance to enter the password. When I removed the redirection (`<`), it correctly prompts for a password. So it appears that somehow, when run via Rails, the STDIN redirection is disrupting the password prompt. I tried with backticks and had the same issue.

I assume that the `mysql` executable must be using some magic so that the STDIN redirection does not disrupt the password prompt, but it appears to be broken when the executable is launched via Rails.

Is Rails overriding System() and if so, is there some way to call the real System()?
Does anyone have other ideas of how to work around this, or what could be happening here?

Comment: Rails doesn't override System. System is core to Ruby for supplying calls to the underlying OS, and, since Rails is completely Ruby code, it'd make no sense.

Comment: From experiments years ago, I found that many executables that require a password won't work when called indirectly. The executables check to see where their input is coming from and if it's not TTY they'll bail. Instead, I'd use ActiveRecord or Sequel to talk to the database and load and iteratively pass the schema commands, or, better yet, use ActiveRecord or Sequel to define the DB as models so that the ORM is aware of what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

The `mysql` executable is skipping the request for a password because in order to except `stdin` for the password, the command needs to be executed with [TTY](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tty_(unix)) enabled. Ruby `system` command and backticks do not execute the command using a TTY enabled interface to the underlying system. There are a couple gems that allow for TTY enabled execution on the command line, I would check out the [tty-command](https://github.com/piotrmurach/tty-command) gem if you’d like to force the command prompt to ask for the password.

Though for the ideal solution that I would suggest, since you’re executing the command from within Rails, you should have access to `Rails.credentials`. I would store the necessary credentials (username and password) for the database within the credentials store, and use this to populate the `-u` and `-P` flag values for the mysql command.  This will avoid the need to prompt for the password entirely.